# why is the error thinking Its not string?

Tags: python, exec

path of file is:

"C:\Users\deana\OneDrive\Marlon's files\Programming\Python\PITT\PITT_LIbrary\Lists\test.txt"

lines of code are:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/deana/OneDrive/Marlon's files/Programming/Python/PITT/PITT_LIbrary/Lists")
exec(open('test.txt'))
```

the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(open('test.txt'))
TypeError: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

also if I try on one line as such:

```
exec(open(r"C:/Users/deana/OneDrive/Marlon's files/Programming/Python/PITT/PITT_LIbrary/Lists/test.txt"))
```

i'ts the same error. (with and without r)

super frustrationg as it reads like i'm not inputting string... but *it is* string!?!
also I've done this litteraly the same way before, restarted IDLE shell, no difference.
ugh! I always get stupid errors with file paths.

Comment: It's not the argument to `open` that the error is complaining about; it's the value `open` *returns* being passed as the argument to `exec`. `open` is returning a value of type `io.TextIOWrapper`, not a `str`, bytes`, or `code` object.

Comment: If you intended to execute the contents of `test.txt`; you would need something like `exec(open('test.txt').read())`.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been using `os.startfile()` to open this.
It was confusing by using .open(). as I was attempting to open in default app.
before, i've used exec.open() to open .py files and guess I got them confused.
exec is just used to open other scripts... need stronger coffee next time.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```py
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/deana/OneDrive/Marlon's files/Programming/Python/PITT/PITT_LIbrary/Lists")
exec(open('test.txt', 'rb'))
```

You can convert the txt file to bytes by opening it with `rb` (**r**ead **b**ytes).

Comment: read bytes returns a `BufferedReader` object like the regular read mode returns a `TextIOWrapper` object. both of which cannot be read by `exec` built-in function. you could call read method before passing it into the `exec` function that would work.

Comment: Well, I don't have access to the OPs files, so I don't know what's in there ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It doesnt matter what is in the file. Reading any file in `rb` will always return `BufferedReader`

Comment: i'm not sure what bufferreader is or textiowrapper. but exec is supposed to open the txt file (or any file) in its nativa application. changing the form, or defining how it should be opened is counterintuitive.